# Excel-outlook VBA 2013 not working on 2016 Outlook version

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm having problems with a macro. It used to work on the 2013 version of outlook and excel but for some reason the CC function has stopped working and I keep getting errors.

With the 2013 version I used the following code to define the CC and BCC:

```
Set sh = Sheets ("Sheet1")

        .to = cell.Value
        .CC = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:C1")
        .BCC = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("D1:D1")
```

This however doesn't work in the 2016 version of my excel and outlook. Every single row in excel need to have its own To , CC and BCC selected from a row in Excel. For some reason it keeps saying CC is not a valid method. object_Mailitem failed.

- Editing the variables behind the .cc and .bcc to "mail@x.com" is working without getting the error. So I assume there is something wrong with the line after the .cc, i've tried multiple solutions which ended up in either the same error or an other error telling me it doesn't recognize the .Send command.

EDIT: added the full code of the macro

```
Sub Send files()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ccontvangen As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("E1:Z1")

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .to = cell.Value
            .cc = "x"
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .Attachments.Add "G:\signature.png", olByValue, 0
            .Body = " "

            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
            Next FileCell
             .Send
        End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Comment: If hard coded string values are working, you might want to try explicitly calling the `.Value` property on your ranges: `sh.Cells(cell.Row, 3).Value`.

Comment: Would help to show more of your code and indicate which lines are causing problems, along with the exact error messages you're getting

Comment: FWIW - `sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("D1:D1")` can be simplified to `sh.Cells(cell.Row, "D")`

Comment: @Comintern It worked out perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar issue where the Subject Line, To, and Cc were not being listed completely.

I figured out the problem by adding a & ";" to the end of each field.